# Return multiple values in ternary operation

Tags: javascript

I cannot expain more than an example:

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 2;
let condition;
condition ? a = 2; b = 10 : false
console.log(a, b)
```

Why this syntax is wrong?

Comment: There's a nice description of the valid syntax at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the assignments in parenthesis and use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which separates the assignments, instead of semicolon, which separates statements.

The semicolon ends the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) before reaching the `:`, which is a needed part of the syntax and this leads to an error.

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 2;
let condition = true;

condition ? (a = 2, b = 10) : false;

console.log(a, b);
```

Instead of taking a conditional operator, you could use [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()).

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 2;
let condition = true;

condition && (a = 2, b = 10);

console.log(a, b);
```

Finally the best approach by using `if`.

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 2;
let condition = true;

if (condition) {
    a = 2;
    b = 10;
}

console.log(a, b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because of operator predescendence, and the ternary only works with expressions, so might just do:

```
condition ? ((a = 2), (b = 10)) : false
```

However, i would prefer:

```
if(condition) {
 a = 2;
 b = 10;
}
```

Comment: I need it inside react render, so in it ternary operation is much simpler

Answer (score 2):

Just to give another option not yet posted, if you don't want to use a standard `if..else`, you could also use [ES6's neat destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which is particularly handy if you've already got an array of values that you want to assign from.

For example: (I've used two different conditions to show both outcomes)

```js
let a = 1 > 2 ? [y, z] = [2, 10] : false;
console.log(a); //a = false;

2 > 1 ? [y, z] = [2, 10] : false;
console.log(y, z); //y = 2, z = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new to javascript and I am not really sure about my answer here, but aren't ternary operators somewhat used like this:

```
condition ? a = 2 : b = 10;
```

Or in your case:

```
condition ? (a = 2, b = 10) : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant run more than 1 "line" or "command" (ending with a semicolon) in the ternary operation. 
You could do

```
let condition;
let a = condition ? 2: 0;
let b = condition ? 10 : 2;
console.log(a, b);
```

which will work for your purpose or if you want to change `a` and `b` in a later point

```
let a = 0;
let b = 0;
let condition;
//later
a = condition ? 2 : a;
b = condition ? 10 : b;
```

both these examples will work with what you need

Answer (score 0):

```js
let condition1 = false;
let {a=0,b=2} = condition1 ? {a:2,b:10} : {}
console.log(a, b)

let condition2 = true;
let {c=0,d=2} = condition2 ? {c:2,d:10} : {}
console.log(c, d)
```